# How to send Private message to everyone who has a specific role? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

The **bot** only sends a private message to me if I have the **SPECIFIED ROLE.**

It does not write to other **users** with the **SPECIFIED ROLE.**

What is the problem?

```
client.on("message", (msg) => {

    if (msg.guild && msg.content.startsWith("!private")) {
      if (msg.author.id === "55430860840......") {

      const text = msg.content.slice("!private".length);
      const staffID = "747217324.......";

      msg.guild.members.cache.forEach((member) => {
       if(member.roles.cache.has(staffID)) {member.send(text)} })
}
}
});
```

Comment: What you're currently attempting to do is API abuse, and could result in a tempban from the API and sometimes Discord as a whole.

Please find a better solution to communicating with your staff members.

Comment: Roles exist to be mentioned. Just mention the role instead of dming each member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do:

```
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
   if (member._roles.includes('<Role ID>')) {
      member.send(<message>)
   }
            
})
```